# Implementing Selection Sort in C

Tags: c, selection-sort

I am trying to implement the Selection Sort Algorithm and here is my attempt:

```
int select(int arr[], int i)
{
    int j, minIndex;
    
    minIndex = i;
    for (j = i + 1; arr[j]; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex])
            minIndex = j;
    }
    return minIndex;
}


void selectionSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i, iMin;
    
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        iMin = select(arr, i);
        if (iMin != i)
        {
            int temp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[iMin];
            arr[iMin] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Even though my code works fine, if there is an element in the array with value zero it fails. Here is an example case:

```
4 1 3 9 0
```

Output:

```
1 3 4 9 0
```

I know that my logic is correct, because it works with other cases, but why is it failing if there is a `0` in the array element?

Comment: Q: What debugger is convenient for you to use?  Q: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Your loop condition is wrong:

```
for (j = i + 1; arr[j]; j++)
```

instead of `arr[j]` you need `j < n`.

2. Renamed `select()` to `selectMin()` to avoid conflict with existing function with that name.  If you specify the length `n` before the array `arr` your can document how the two are related with current compilers.
3. Extracted the `swap()` function.
4. Minimized scope of variables.
5. `size_t` instead of `int` for indices as they are non-negative.  The type difference also helps you distinguish between the indices of the array (`size_t`) the values of the array (`int`) which was the root cause of your troubles.
6. Hard-coded your test case and implemented a `print()` functions to verify correct result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(size_t n, int a[n]) {
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%d%s", a[i], i + 1 < n ? ", " : "\n");
}

size_t selectMin(size_t n, int arr[n], int i) {
    size_t minIndex = i;
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        if (arr[j] < arr[minIndex])
            minIndex = j;
    return minIndex;
}

void selectionSort(size_t n, int arr[n]) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        size_t iMin = selectMin(n, arr, i);
        if (iMin != i)
            swap(arr + i, arr + iMin);
    }
}

void swap(int *a, int *b) {
    int tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;
}

int main(void) {
    int a[] = {4, 1, 3, 9, 0};
    selectionSort(sizeof a / sizeof *a, a);
    print(sizeof a / sizeof *a, a);
}
```

and the output is:

```
0, 1, 3, 4, 9
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop

```
for (j = i + 1; arr[j]; j++)
```

is problematic because of the loop condition `arr[j]`. As a condition it's equivalent to `arr[j] != 0`. C doesn't have any concept of "null values" like e.g. C# or Java.

You need to pass the array length to the `select` function, you can't rely on the array data itself to know when and where the array ends.

Using the array data itself will either lead to premature loop end if the data contains zeros. Or will go out of bounds if the array data doesn't contain any zeros.

Comment: You've certainly pointed out the correct problem area, but "C doesn't have any concept of 'null values'"?  The language spec devotes attention to null pointer values, as well as to the null character which serves to terminate null terminated strings.  And all that is common in less formal discussion, too.  I'm not quite sure what you meant by that remark, but whatever it is, I'm sure there is a better way to phrase it.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Null pointers and the null terminator are actual values (the null-terminator have the value `0` and that's commonly the value for null pointers as well). C doesn't have the concept of "this variable have no value" like C# or Java.

Comment: I'm not sure about C#, but Java has no such concept either.  Java's null is an actual value, with its own type, that variables and expressions of reference type may take.  And that variables and expressions that are *not* of reference type cannot take.  This is pretty closely analogous to C if we match "reference type" with "pointer type" and "null" with "null pointer".